# Can I access a file's static variable from another file via a pointer?

Tags: c, pointers, global-variables, static-variables

I have two files: `uart.c`, it has tow variables in the 4-5th lines:

```
static FIFO inputBuffer;
static FIFO outputBuffer;
```

And `buffer.c`, which has sevenal functions to manage `FIFO` structs, like:

```
void FIFOGet(FIFO* buffer, uint8_t* data, uint8_t length)
```

These functions are for general use, so that I will never deal with `inputBuffer` in `buffer.c` directly, only via a pointer. The ablove function is called from `uart.c` as:

```
FIFOGet(&inputBuffer, someArray, n)
```

But inside this function I lost `buffer`'s value (I know that `inputBuffer` is located at 0x04f0 when I call the function, but `buffer`'s value is 0x04ea - which points to `outputBuffer`, I'm 140% sure the function call is fine, I don't pass `outputBuffer`). This happens because I declared `inputBuffer` as `static`? If so, I'll remove it, but should I put `extern FIFO inputBuffer` into `buffer.c`? I'd like if someone could explain how it exactly works.

Comment: read up about `static` variables...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C, by default any symbols that are at file scope ("global" variables and functions) are "published" in the object file. This is often useful - but it also prevents those exact symbols from being published by other modules.

So to be a nice module, if a file-scope symbol is not going to be accessed outside of the file you should declare it as `static`. That means that the symbol won't be published in the object file - that is all. You can still pass pointers to that symbol to other modules: they just can't access it by name.

If you did put `extern FIFO inputBuffer;` into `buffer.c`, you'd get a linker error. It would look through all the modules for a published symbol `inputBuffer` - and not find one.

Comment: For the extern-thing, I mean after I remove `static`in `uart.c`, I put `extern` into `buffer.c`, so that the variable would be a "true-global", which is not a problem for me. But I'll access that virable only via pointer, and I'm not sure in this case `extern` has any affects.

Comment: If you remove the `static`, but *don't* put `extern` in `buffer.c`, then you'll get a compiler error: `Unknown symbol inputBuffer`. But I don't understand: you say `FIFOGet()` has the correct value for `buffer` at the beginning, but it gets _lost_? Surely that's the problem here? You shouldn't be trying to re-assign `inputBuffer` to `buffer` - you should be finding out how `buffer` lost the value in the first place!